# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

In some phones the following error is occurring. I am not able to identify the problem by reviewing the log details. log details and xml file contents can view below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adit.bangkit.plagroid/com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.ui.activities.SettingsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67 in com.adit.bangkit.plagroid:layout/activity_settings: Binary XML file line #67 in com.adit.bangkit.plagroid:layout/activity_settings: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67 in com.adit.bangkit.plagroid:layout/activity_settings: Binary XML file line #67 in com.adit.bangkit.plagroid:layout/activity_settings: Error inflating class <unknown>
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67 in com.adit.bangkit.plagroid:layout/activity_settings: Error inflating class <unknown>
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:934)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:954)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1008)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
    at com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.databinding.ActivitySettingsBinding.inflate(ActivitySettingsBinding.java:105)
    at com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.databinding.ActivitySettingsBinding.inflate(ActivitySettingsBinding.java:99)
    at com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.ui.activities.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.kt:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
```

here is my SettingsActivity.kt

```
    class SettingsActivity : BaseActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySettingsBinding

    // A variable for user details which will be initialized later on.
    private lateinit var mUserDetails: User

    /**
     * This function is auto created by Android when the Activity Class is created.
     */
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        //This call the parent constructor
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySettingsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        // This is used to align the xml view to this class
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setupActionBar()


        binding.tvEdit.setOnClickListener(this@SettingsActivity)
        binding.btnLogout.setOnClickListener(this@SettingsActivity)
        binding.llAddress.setOnClickListener(this@SettingsActivity)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        getUserDetails()
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        if (v != null) {
            when (v.id) {

                R.id.tv_edit -> {
                    val intent = Intent(this@SettingsActivity, UserProfileActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_USER_DETAILS, mUserDetails)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }

                R.id.ll_address -> {
                    val intent = Intent(this@SettingsActivity, AddressListActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }

                R.id.btn_logout -> {

                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()

                    val intent = Intent(this@SettingsActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * A function for actionBar Setup.
     */
    private fun setupActionBar() {

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbarSettingsActivity)

        val actionBar = supportActionBar
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_white_color_back_24dp)
        }

        binding.toolbarSettingsActivity.setNavigationOnClickListener { onBackPressed() }
    }

    /**
     * A function to get the user details from firestore.
     */
    private fun getUserDetails() {

        // Show the progress dialog
        showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))

        // Call the function of Firestore class to get the user details from firestore which is already created.
        FirestoreClass().getUserDetails(this@SettingsActivity)
    }

    /**
     * A function to receive the user details and populate it in the UI.
     */
    fun userDetailsSuccess(user: User) {

        mUserDetails = user

        // Hide the progress dialog
        hideProgressDialog()

        // Load the image using the Glide Loader class.
        GlideLoader(this@SettingsActivity).loadUserPicture(user.image, binding.ivUserPhoto)
        binding.tvName.text = user.firstName
        binding.tvName.text = user.lastName
        binding.tvGender.text = user.gender
        binding.tvEmail.text = user.email
        binding.tvMobileNumber.text = "${user.mobile}"
    }
}
```

and this is the XML layout from SettingsActivity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.SettingsActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_header_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/header_image_height">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_header_bg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/auth_screens_background" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_settings_activity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/toolbar_title_paddingStart"
                    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                    android:text="@string/title_settings"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_title_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_user_image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/settings_user_image_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/settings_user_image_size"
            android:layout_below="@id/fl_header_bg"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/settings_user_image_marginTop">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_user_photo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/settings_user_picture_margin"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_user_placeholder" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/user_image_background" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/fl_header_bg"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/item_grey_border_background"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/settings_edit_label_marginStartEnd"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/settings_edit_label_marginTopBottom"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/settings_edit_label_marginStartEnd"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/settings_edit_label_marginTopBottom"
            android:text="@string/lbl_edit"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            android:textSize="@dimen/settings_edit_label_textSize" />

        <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPTextViewBold
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/fl_user_image"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/settings_name_marginTop"
                android:textColor="@color/colorDarkGrey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/settings_name_textSize"
                tools:text="Tri Aditya" />

        <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_gender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_name"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/settings_info_marginTop"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            android:textSize="@dimen/settings_info_textSize"
            tools:text="Male" />

        <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_gender"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/settings_info_marginTop"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            android:textSize="@dimen/settings_info_textSize"
            tools:text="triaditya@gmail.com" />

        <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_mobile_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_email"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/settings_info_marginTop"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            android:textSize="@dimen/settings_info_textSize"
            tools:text="+628123456789" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_mobile_number"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/settings_address_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/item_grey_border_background"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/settings_address_padding">

            <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/settings_lbl_addresses_margin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/lbl_addresses"
                android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/settings_lbl_addresses_textSize" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_vector_chevron_right" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.adit.bangkit.plagroid.utils.MSPButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/ll_address"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/settings_button_marginStartEnd"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/settings_button_marginTopBottom"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/settings_button_marginStartEnd"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/settings_button_marginTopBottom"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/btn_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/btn_padding"
            android:text="@string/btn_lbl_logout"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_textSize" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I can't find what is the problem for this random issue. for any positive reply thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to remove `android:scaleType="fitXY"` from `iv_user_photo`

Comment: Check where is your `@drawable/ic_user_placeholder`. if it is in drawable-v24 or something different then moving this icon/image to drawable folder may help you

Comment: Can you please explain how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: Did you get any solution , I am also getting error like Resource not found

Answer (score 0):

my problem was in the use of: `@dimen/` in the layouts. When rotating the phone or tablet and using different screen sizes, the crashes appeared because it couldn't find the dimen reference and the saved instance state became null. Make sure every reference in every screensize are correct, errors are underlined in red but it shows no errors when compiling, and the file name will not be red although it contains errors! That's why this errors are so difficult to find:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Remove any drawables from the xml file, I'd had the same error and this had worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).